# Why do so many guys deny their lower body?

Tags: exercise, legs, upper-body-workout, chest, isolation

So I have noticed a considerable amount of guys in my gym will not do any leg work(as much as 50% on some days).... All they do is bench and do bicep curls... Why don't a lot of guys wanna do leg work?

Comment: Because they are lazy and the squat is just about one of the most taxing exercises you can do.

Comment: The why on this is probably very opinion based... But in general, a lot of times vanity rules... The glamour muscles get worked more, while the others get neglected.

Comment: In addition to the "mirror muscles" issue, bench pressing and bicep curling are relatively straight forward. Lower body compound lifts have more technique involved and people never take the time to learn. For everyone doing squats, watch how few actually get them right.

Comment: You should consult with this [guy](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/25878/i-am-doing-the-bench-press-7-times-a-week).

Comment: While the question *might* be opinion-based, it's valid; is there a reason for trying to close it?

Answer (score 2):

Many reasons, primarily because leg muscles aren't as visible and often not considered as important aestetically. This is the same reason people don't workout their back enough. Of course, in the long run, doing arms and chest will make you look silly and it will be obvious that you aren't really strong.

Some people also think that because they ride their bike to work/to the gym, they don't need to workout their legs. This is not true.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's many reasons:

- Some likely do leg work but perhaps run a split routine and leg day is a day you're not in the gym.
- Some may do a leg intensive sport and working the upper body in the gym is a way to compensate
- On the other hand some may do an upper body intensive sport and so legs just aren't a goal for them
- Finally there will be some people who don't care about or enjoy training legs.

In the end though it doesn't really matter, provided you are happy with what you are doing in the gym I wouldn't worry about deficiencies in other people's exercise.